# APIM request xml validation

Tags: biztalk, azure-api-management

Is there a way to validate the output of the json-to-xml policy against a schema?

one of our partner sents a request to APIM that is routed to backend biztalk and want to validate the request before to route it to biztalk

Answer (score 0):

No.  But...even you could, in a trading partner scenario, I wouldn't because you can better handle the issue in the BizTalk app vs. APIM.

Comment: we make a workaround within biztalk via an xslt map before a message validation within the orchestration but it introduces some non desired scenarios. is there other tip?

Comment: You could try to use xsl-transform policy in APIM to ensure validity of XML. Or set-body with liquid template for the same purpose. Other that than there is not much else besides manually traversing XML tree and validating it "by hand".

Comment: @Hichamveo Why are you doing a map before validation?  And what are the 'non desired scenarios'.  Don't over think this.  Xml validation is really required in most cases.

Comment: The validation fails when json data  not respect our XML tags order

Comment: @Hichamveo Well, OK.  That's a problem for the sender to address.  Or, you can change you schema to allow elements in any order.

Comment: I can't change the schema because it's used to receive data from another partner from a flat file where the order is important. it's a multi partner source half flow data for send to other partners

Comment: @Hichamveo Sure, but you can still change the schema used for that one partner.

Comment: thanks @Johns-305 for your help but this is not what i'm expecting

Comment: @Hichamveo Well, what are you expecting then?  There are easy solutions to all these issues, you just can't put yourself in arbitrary boxes.